# Synaptic complains that JOSM no longer has a Release file

Tags: apt, 20.04, https

I have opened JOSM ticket [21855](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/21855) for this.
Inside, you will find the apt update command that I determined being the cause (certificate).
I responded to our friends' remarks that my system seems normal.
Would anyone versed in certificates find out what is happening?

Comment: Please include relevant commands and output in *this* post using code formatting (https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). Also add the version of Ubuntu you're using.

Comment: What installation did you follow?  The one at https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Download seems pretty straight forward.  I did a test run of it and it installed the key and it was trusted without issue in focal.

Comment: Every detail is in the JOSM bug.
Installation of what?
I used Synaptics to try to upgrade JOSM and it no longer worked.